# Find closest neighbor element with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sorting, dom, nearest-neighbor

We're working on a SmartTV web application which has a layout as pictured below. Every tile can be focused and is "clickable". The user navigates with the arrow keys of his TV remote controller. On every click on one of the arrow keys, the app is searching for its closest neighbor in the given direction and sets a new focus.

The current implementation is working well but is terrible slow. To find the next element it can take up to 300ms (on a tv) or even more, if there are many elements on the page.

***What is the most performant way with TypeScript, to find the closest element by the following rules***

1. Horizonzal navigation: Focus need to stay in line and should never go to the upper or bottom lane.
2. Vertical navigation: Focus should never skip its upper or lower lane, even an element 2 lanes away is closer
3. No element should be returned, if non is available in the given direction

Our working but slow code

```js
    focusNext(direction, sourceRect): void {
        const possibleTargets = this.getTargetsByDirection(sourceRect, direction);
        
        if (possibleTargets.length) {
            this.focusClosestElement(sourceRect, possibleTargets);
        }
    }

    getTargetsByDirection(sourceRect, direction) {
        const possibleTargets = [];
    
        this.allElementsOnPage.forEach((element) => {
            const targetRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    
            if (
                (direction === 'up' && this.isAboveOf(sourceRect, targetRect)) ||
                (direction === 'right' && this.isRightOf(sourceRect, targetRect)) ||
                (direction === 'down' && this.isBelowOf(sourceRect, targetRect)) ||
                (direction === 'left' && this.isLeftOf(sourceRect, targetRect))
            ) {
                possibleTargets.push({
                    element,
                    boundingClientRect: targetRect
                });
            }
        });
    
        return possibleTargets;
    }

    focusClosestElement(sourceRect, targets): void {
        const distances = [];

        targets.forEach((element) => {
            const distance = Math.hypot(
                (element.boundingClientRect.left + element.boundingClientRect.right) / 2 -
                    (sourceRect.left + sourceRect.right) / 2,
                element.boundingClientRect.top - sourceRect.top
            );

            distances.push(distance);
        });

        const closestIndex = distances.indexOf(Math.min(...distances));

        if (closestIndex > -1) {
            targets[closestIndex].element.focus()
        }
    }

    isAboveOf(sourceRect, targetRect): boolean {
        return targetRect.top < sourceRect.top && !this.hasElementsBetween(targetRect, sourceRect));
    }

    isRightOf(sourceRect, targetRect): boolean {
        return targetRect.left > sourceRect.left && this.intersectHorizontally(targetRect, sourceRect);
    }

    isBelowOf(sourceRect, targetRect): boolean {
        return targetRect.top > sourceRect.top && !this.hasElementsBetween(targetRect, sourceRect);
    }

    isLeftOf(sourceRect, targetRect): boolean {
        return targetRect.left < sourceRect.left && this.intersectHorizontally(targetRect, sourceRect);
    }

    hasElementsBetween(sourceRect, targetRect): boolean {
        return this.allElementsOnPage.some((element: HTMLElement) => {
            const boundingClientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            return (
                (sourceRect.bottom < boundingClientRect.top && targetRect.top > boundingClientRect.bottom) ||
                (sourceRect.top > boundingClientRect.bottom && targetRect.bottom < boundingClientRect.top)
            );
        });
    }

    intersectHorizontally(targetRect, sourceRect): boolean {
        return (
            (targetRect.top >= sourceRect.top && targetRect.top <= sourceRect.bottom) ||
            (targetRect.top <= sourceRect.top && targetRect.bottom >= sourceRect.bottom) ||
            (targetRect.bottom >= sourceRect.top && targetRect.bottom <= sourceRect.bottom)
        );
    }
```

The HTML (simplified)

- All items within a lane are wrapped in a container
- Items are just a `div` or `li` which are styled to appear in a row
- The number of lanes and items are dynamic
- The items are added to an array `allElementsOnPage` on creation

```html
    <main>
      <div class="lane">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
      </div>

      <div class="lane">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
      </div>

      <div class="lane">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
      </div>

      <div class="lane">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

[image: Layout mock]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :-) I added the simplified html markup

Comment: Your sample HTML seems to always have the same number of items in a row, but the picture looks like the number of items in a row varies dramatically, and like the width of them varies markedly (which I assume you want to take into account). I recommend creating a runnable [mcve] with representative layout. (Runnable = Stack Snippets [the `[<>]` toolbar button]; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).)

Comment: Yeah, your right. The HTML is simplified. The number of elements vary from lane to lane and the size can be different as well. Thanks for runnable link, i'll try that.